# Autoplay video in Bootstrap modal window on modal opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, video

I have a Bootstrap 3.3.7 modal window which contains a video using the HTML5 video tag, e.g.

```
<video controls autoplay>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The trouble with this is that when my web page loads, the video starts playing (even though it cannot be "seen" since the modal is closed, the audio also plays).

I understand that the `autoplay` tag is doing this. But how can I get the video to autoplay when the modal is loaded? And stop when the modal is closed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `shown.bs.modal` and `hidden.bs.modal` events to run some javascript code when the modal is shown/hidden:

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#video1')[0].play();
})
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#video1')[0].pause();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <video controls id="video1" style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin:0 auto; frameborder:0;">
          <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a javascript function to start the video and call it when the modal is loaded: (and remove the autoplay attribute )
Here is an example:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
function playVid() { vid.play(); }
```

Answer (score -4):

**strong text**
    
        
            
                ×

```html
run my snippet in the botonm
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

autoPlayYouTubeModal();

//FUNCTION TO GET AND AUTO PLAY YOUTUBE VIDEO FROM DATATAG
function autoPlayYouTubeModal() {
  var trigger = $("body").find('[data-toggle="modal"]');
  trigger.click(function () {
      var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
          videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-theVideo"),
          videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?autoplay=1";
      $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
      $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
          $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
      });
      $('.modal').click(function () {
          $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
      });
    //video play on click
    $('.video-player-main iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{func":"playVideo":""}', '*');
  });
}
});
```

```css
.btn{margin-left:20%;margin-top:20%}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="video-player-wrapper">
                <div class="video-player-main">
                 
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal1" data-theVideo="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XsI9F3n-Bog">Open Model</a>
                </div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="videoModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModal" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-body">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <div>
     <iframe width="100%" height="350" src="" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```